# How does Aerospike handles the CAP theorem?

Tags: high-availability, aerospike, consistency

I want to use aerospike in distributed system. Aerospike official documentation says:

**The Aerospike system is classified as AP**

Can anyone put some light on the same? How Aerospike ensures AP mode in distributed environment.

Comment: You should have read a bit further down the page. "In Aerospike 4, Strong Consistency has been introduced. With this algorithm, cluster splits and partitions carefully manage which section of the cluster is still available, disallowing any potentially conflicting writes."   
 Strong Consistency is at the top of the CP hierarchy https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/acid.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aerospike offers both AP mode and Strong Consistency Mode which passes the third party Jepsen Tests.  Visit jepsen.io for their take on various distributed databases and specifically about Aerospike here:  http://jepsen.io/analyses/aerospike-3-99-0-3

Comment: In other words Aerospike can operate in AP mode or in CP mode per the CAP theorem but not both at the same time. So a cluster can support applications using either mode (or both) but specific use cases for that cluster must choose between favoring A or C.

Answer (score 2):

The Aerospike documentation includes a couple of sections you should read:

- [Architecture Overview - Consistency](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/consistency.html)
- [Feature Guide - Consistency](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/consistency.html)